# context not defined in IIFE after gulp bundling and uglify

Tags: javascript, gulp, iife

I have a file `myFile.js` with a simple IIFE in it:

```
(function() {
    console.log(this);       // this is the window object
})()
```

I'm using gulp with browserify, babel and uglify to handle the file and create a dist version that is included by a HTML script tag:

```
// gulp build task
function build() {
    let fileUploaderBundle = browserify('./js/myFile.js', { debug: true })
        .transform(babel.configure({
            presets: ['@babel/env']
        }));

    return fileUploaderBundle
        .bundle()
        .on('error', (error) => {
            console.error(error); this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(source('myFile.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({
            loadMaps: true
        }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(dest('./dist/js'));
};
```

in the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/myFile.js"></script>
```

but then dist/js/myFile.js logs `undefined` instead of logging the window object... Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the dist use `use strict`?

Comment: yes, you are right... I don't know from where it comes from but something in the process added `use strict`

Comment: any idea about which step is adding it?

Comment: I googled around but didn't find anything concrete, don't know enough about the build process unfortunately, but you might be able to figure it out by removing calls until the `use strict` goes away, to narrow down the source

Comment: Googling around, I see people having problems with one area of code adding `use strict` outside of a function declaration, and file concatenation ends up moving it to the global scope instead of just being scoped to the file it was written in (because the line wasn't scoped to anything other than a JS file). The recommendation is to only add `use strict` inside of a function (which can be an IIFE), to keep the scope where you want it.

Comment: For example, here's an issue on some library https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/269. You may want to see if any of your imported libraries have `use strict` in them.

Comment: thanks for help; I see now that it was due to an `import` statement, since modules are always in strict mode